# Making Spring aware of Jersey filter

Tags: spring, jersey, servlet-filters

I have a class which implements ContainerRequestFilter, i want to inject some spring dependencies into it so i need to make Spring aware of the Jersey filter. The filter itself is configured in my web.xml with the Jersey servlet

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.MyFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

The filter class then attempts to inject the Manager bean. In order to make spring aware of the Filter bean i have defined the bean in my applicationContext.xml and included.

```
@Component
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

@Autowired
private Manager manager;
```

I've attempted to make the filter bean visible by forcing Spring to use proxy generated classes however this is not working

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<aop:aspect-autoproxy />    

<bean id="filter" class="com.MyFilter">
    <property name="manager" ref="Manager" />
</bean>
```

Any suggestions on how i can edit existing code to allow the filter see spring beans?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something that is quite common for Spring Security applications.  You should utilize the [`DelegatingFilterProxy`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html) for this.

You will add this filter to your web.xml via the `<filter>` tag, and you then configure it as a bean in your application container.  You can then use it to delegate to a Spring configured filter that you have in your application context.

I am unfamiliar with how Jersey's `SpringServlet` work, but that is how I would delegate to a Spring configured filter.

Answer (score 8):

Since you are using Jersey's Spring Servlet, spring dependencies can be injected into the filter using the annotation [@InjectParam](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.5/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/core/InjectParam.html)

```
//@Component -> This is not required.
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

@InjectParam
private Manager manager;
```

I feel this is the idiomatic way of using Jersey and Spring together.

Comment: The `@InjectParam` works for me, but if I remove the `<param-value>` from web.xml Jersey does not load the filter.

Comment: When I add `@InjectParam` I get a SEVERE: missing dependency error; injection from Spring into resource classes with `@Inject` works (but `@Inject` is not picked up in container filters). Is there some step I'm missing?